# jquery triggered when user scrolls in div

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is scrollable:

```
.stepDetailView{
    float:right;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I'm trying to detect when the user scrolls in the area.  I know that **$(window).scroll(function(){ });** works if I'm trying to detect scrolling for the entire window, but on my page, scrolling is only enabled in the div .stepDetailView.

I tried

```
$('.stepDetailView').scroll(function(){
  console.log("scrolling");
 });
```

but the log never appears in the console. Is there some other way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error!

It's not:

```
$('.stepDetailView').scroll(function({
  console.log("scrolling");
});
```

but:

```
$('.stepDetailView').scroll(function() {
  console.log("scrolling");
});
```

or even:

```
$('.stepDetailView').on('scroll', function() {
  console.log("scrolling");
});
```

And then it [**WORKS !!!**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ufMwW/)

Comment: whoops, that was a typo on my part.  I actually did have the correct syntax in my code, but it still doesn't work (I tried both options you suggested).

Comment: never mind, I just wrapped it all in a $(function() {}); and it works!  thanks!

Comment: @scientiffic - that's why I added it in jsFiddle, as it's not really needed there, but I added it anyway as a reminder, as it is a common mistake!